# How to center image inside diamond shape div? - CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a diamond shape div that contains image and text/title.

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 25px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.wrap img {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.travel-title {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2178/3531465579_8bff044e9b_z.jpg?zz=1" />
  <div class="travel-title">Tittle</div>
</div>
```

There are three things I would like to achieve:

1) How can I center image inside diamond shape div? This is because the image must be changed in the CMS by the customer.

2) How can I center text/title in diamond shape div? Also has to be changed by customer.

I have tried to achieved it with this piece of code without success:

```
.travel-title {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

3) Is it possible to zoom out image a bit?

Solutions with JS, JQuery would also work.

Any advice is appreciated.

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FITTING IMAGE**

I played around with math calculations from tip in comments and for my case this is what worked to make picture fit diamond shape although they are different size.

```
.wrap img {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: left center;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: calc(170% - 8.28px);
    height: calc(150% - 8.28px);
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
```

Comment: related for some math calculation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689026/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for a tip. I have been playing around to find suitable math calc for my case and I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How can I center image inside diamond shape div? This is because the image must be changed in the CMS by the customer.

You are already do this with transform-origin: left center; Is there a different way you want this centered?

2. How can I center text/title in diamond shape div? Also has to be changed by customer.

Please see the CSS below to see the changes I made to your CSS class.

3. Is it possible to zoom out image a bit?

I zoomed out the image by changing the height of the image. I added some margin to the top of the image to center the image vertically. The issue with centering images vertically and horizontally inside of custom divs is not knowing the size of the image that one of your customers will be uploading. I do not know what CMS you are using but if there is a way to crop the image via code or prompt the user to upload a picture with a certain dimension it will be easier for you to design this element of the site.

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 25px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.wrap img {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.title-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.travel-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2178/3531465579_8bff044e9b_z.jpg?zz=1" />
  <div class="title-wrap">
    <div class="travel-title">Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```